# Why can't I `print` an array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, pdo

I'm new to this, and I've looked on many different posts here, as well as on a lot of other resources found on google, but I'm still struggling with arrays.

in my html, I'm basically trying to display a sum total of a column of dollar amounts in my database.

Here's my HTML/PHP:

```
 <div class="col-sm-2">                  
    <h1><?php get_sum_income(); ?></h1>
 </div>
```

and here's my external PHP file with the function it calls:

```
function get_sum_income() {
require(ROOT_PATH . "inc/database.php");

try {
    $results = $db->prepare("SELECT SUM(cat_amount) FROM categories WHERE is_income = '1';");
    $results->execute();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo ("ERROR: Data could not be retrieved from the database." . $e);
    exit;
}
$sum_income = $results->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
print $sum_income;
```

};

I keep getting an "array to string conversion" error, and I know it has to do with my understanding of arrays (or lack thereof).  I've looked around, and I just need help with my specific situation.

Also, is how I'm accessing the function the best way to do this?

Comment: Read up on http://php.net/arrays then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't print or echo arrays. You can, however, print a specific element of it:

```
echo $myArray['foo'];
```

Or, you can [`var_dump`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) or [`print_r`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) it.

Answer (score 5):

You can't [`print`](https://www.php.net/print) an array. `print` is for scalars. PHP is trying to convert your array to a string so that it can `print` it, but even its own attempt at this fails, because it's simply not supported.

You can [`print_r`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) it, though!

---

**Update** Sounds like you want to retrieve, on its own, the single element of the array that is your database query result. It's in an array because PHP doesn't *know* ahead of time that your resultset will only have a single column in it.

In your case, you'd write:

```
print $sum_income['SUM(cat_amount)'];
```

This is pretty unwieldy, though. You can shorten it by giving the column an alias in your MySQL query:

```
SELECT SUM(`cat_amount`) AS `mySum` FROM `categories` WHERE `is_income` = '1';
```

Then:

```
$row = $results->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
print $row['mySum'];
```

<sub>*(I've improved the variable name, too!)*</sub>

Comment: Ok, that helped, but now I'm getting the output "Array ( [SUM(cat_amount)] => 1800.24 )".  I had tried print_r before, but I think I'm struggling about how to access just the sum total to display on the page.

Comment: See my answer. You can print/echo specific elements of an array.

Comment: @user1476992: I've updated it.